# JavaFX textfield backspace not working

Tags: java, javafx

I have a textfield  in java

```
    TextField addTask = new TextField();
    addTask.setPromptText("Task");
    addTask.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getCode());
         }
     });
```

Everything here works,except the backspace button.When i click it `BACK_SPACE` is being shown in the console,but nothing gets deleted from the field.Why is that?

Comment: Backspacing should happen on KEY_RELEASED, so maybe you are a bit too early in processing keys.

Comment: @JoopEggen the problem is not the `eventhandler`,it's the fact that it's not deleting anything

Comment: Your code works fine for me and text gets deleted as expected. Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Try it out in a new tine application, maybe some shortcut got done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextField addTask = new TextField();
addTask.setPromptText("Task");
addTask.setOnKeyPressed(ke-> System.out.println(ke.getCode()));
```